# vb.net webbrowser if statement

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I developed a web browser along with a custom address bar (combobox).  I am saving all of the history that a user browsers to in that combobox using my.settings. Here is my problem.  I am prefixing every site with "http://" just to make it correct.  I do correctly process https, its only when nothing is typed in front of an address, I prefix with http.  I am able to save history just fine, my problem is its creating a duplicate because http is typed in by the user so "http://cnn.com" is in the history list, but cnn.com is not so when user types in cnn.com it sees it as new and appends http://cnn.com to the list and it is a dup.  Below is my if statement:  The first line is where I try and say if this site already exists, don't add it, just browse to it.

```
Private Sub btncustomsite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncustomsite.Click
        If ComboBox1.Items.Contains(ComboBox1.Text) Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("ENTER A WEBSITE ADDRESS", , "Warning")
            ComboBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text.StartsWith("https") Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text.StartsWith("http") Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
        ElseIf Not ComboBox1.Text.StartsWith("http") Then
            ComboBox1.Text = "http://" + ComboBox1.Text
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
        ElseIf Not ComboBox1.Text.EndsWith(".com") Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("google.com")
            WaitForPageLoad()
            SendKeys.Send(ComboBox1.Text)
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        Else
            ComboBox1.Text = "http://" + ComboBox1.Text
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("http://" + ComboBox1.Text)
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: your code is doing that - this is easy to debug using a breakpoint when doing what you described for "cnn".  The `Else` block should check if the new text exists in the list before adding it

Comment: ahhhhhh how stupid of me.  Thanks.  Figured it out just by reading your msg.  I should look for "http://" + " " + Combobox1.text

Comment: yep, that worked.  Thanks.  You want to set that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit is flawed:

```
Else
    ComboBox1.Text = "http://" + ComboBox1.Text
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("http://" + ComboBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
```

You want something like this:

```
Else
    Dim tmp As String = "http://" & ComboBox1.Text
    ' only add if the new text is not there
    If ComboBox1.Items.Contains(tmp) = False Then ComboBox1.Items.Add(tmp)
    ComboBox1.Text = tmp
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(ComboBox1.Text)
```

You could have set a breakpoint at the start of the procedure; then performed the steps described for `cnn` to watch what happens

Comment: Thanks I think I'll take your advice and declare a variable and use that instead.

Comment: since it uses the same string 2ce using a var prevents a typo (test one version, add another).  that happens a lot with copy-paste code  when you forget to update all the places it exists.  Also, `&` is the preferred operator for string concatenation.